# Issue with installing R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using Version 1.1.453 of RStudio. I'm receiving an error when trying to install R Shiny using the following code (note: I've tried several different mirrors).

```
install.packages("shiny", repo='http://nbcgib.uesc.br/mirrors/cran/', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Here's the error message I'm getting. Any sense of what's going on?

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/NHK/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘rlang’


There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
   binary  source needs_compilation
httpuv  1.3.3 1.4.4.1              TRUE
shiny   1.0.2   1.1.0             FALSE

Binaries will be installed
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of 
C/C++/Fortran: ‘later’ ‘promises’ ‘rlang’
 These will not be installed
trying URL 

'http://nbcgib.uesc.br/mirrors/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/httpuv_1.3.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 872756 bytes (852 KB)
 downloaded 852 KB

 package ‘httpuv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\NHK\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCqqSmI\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘shiny’

trying URL 'http://nbcgib.uesc.br/mirrors/cran/src/contrib/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2350156 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

ERROR: dependencies 'later', 'promises', 'rlang' are not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/NHK/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
 running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
"C:\Users\NHK\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"
  C:\Users\N~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCqqSmI/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.1.0.
 tar.gz' had status 1

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\NHK\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCqqSmI\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Try it with http://cran.rstudio.com/ as the repo.

Comment: R 3.2 is rather old. I would either try to update R or use an old CRAN snapshot as provided by MRAN to avoid getting recent packages that are incompatible with your version of R. The first method would be my preference.

Comment: I have answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101296/cannot-install-the-shiny-package-in-r/52101950#52101950). Hope it helps.