# Cannot install the shiny package in R

Tags: r, shiny, install.packages

I am trying to install the shiny package in R but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: dependencies 'later', 'promises', 'rlang' are not available for 
package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/sawyer.keels/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/shiny'

The downloaded source packages are in

‘C:\Users\sawyer.keels\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuWfNw6\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\sawyer.keels\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\SAWYER~1.KEE\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuWfNw6/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("shiny") :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
```

If anyone has had this issue in the past I would appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: If you really are using R version 3.2.x that is rather old and you might want to upgrade, if you can.

Comment: Yeah I downloaded the newest version of R and everything is up and running, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the dependency packages:

```
install.packages(c("later","promises","rlang"))
```

Thereafter try to install shiny again:

```
install.packages("shiny")
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I updated `r`:

```
install.packages("installr")
```

and then: `updateR()`

This made the package run.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the suggested solution did not solve my case as
I detected the point of glitch as I attempted to install promises, which was magrittr seemed not installed. It was found in the error message lines.
Thus, install.packages("magrittr").
Then promises was installed and httpuv as well.
shiny is now installed normally.
Issue resolved.